# Creating a function to input data into spreadsheet via message dialogue.

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Complete newcomer to programming here. I'm a little lost.

This is for a character database for an online tabletop rpg group. I'm trying to create a function that will open up a text dialogue that will:

- Ask which players participated
- How much gold and exp were earned

The function then needs to find the rows associated with the entered player names and add the gold and exp values to pre-existing values.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a "Write code for me" site. If you edit to include a function that you have written, and ask how/why your attempt to perform a specific task with said code is not working, and provide some proof of a reasonable effort to fix the issue yourself, then you are asking a good question. Otherwise, you have a very broad request that has no real answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll keep that in mind. I've been doing my best to figure it out myself, but every site and tutorial I check doesn't make much sense to me. I feel like I'm getting nowhere at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement following steps,

- Override onOpen() method to add a custom menu in the Spreadsheet. Add
  a submenu under it. On clicking this sub menu a HTML form will be
  opened.
- Design a HTML page with all required inputs and invoke this
  HTML page from submenu click suggested in the step 1. Add a button in
  this HTML page.
- On click event of the button suggested in step 2
  write a method which will perform search and insert operation in
  Excel file.

Sample snippet for all 3 steps,

**Appscript code**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Filter')
  .addItem('Set Filter', 'menuItem1')
  .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  fetchForm();
}

function fetchForm() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setWidth(530)
  .setHeight(540)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);//index is HTML filename
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Create New Rule');  
}

function processForm(myForm) {

  Logger.log("INFO:       Received data: "+myForm.inboxVal);      
}
```

**index.html**

```
<form class="form-style-7" id="myForm">
<ul>
<li>
    <label for="inbox">Inbox Filter</label>
    <input type="text" id="inboxVal" name="inboxVal" maxlength="100">
    <span>Enter Inbox Search Criteria Here</span>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="button" value="Create Rule"  onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().processForm(this.form)">   
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.